# JPA only executes first select statement in union?

Tags: jpa, jpql

I've written a JPQL statement that unions multiple select statements, each of which selects a different string constant.  A simplified version of the query would look something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 'A' AS widget_type
  FROM WidgetA widgetA
  WHERE widgetA.creationTimestamp > :cutoff
UNION SELECT DISTINCT 'B' AS widget_type
  FROM WidgetB widgetB
  WHERE widgetB.creationTimestamp > :cutoff
```

The query doesn't cause any errors but I'm not getting the result I expect.  I see that the generated SQL doesn't have any unions - it only queries the table from the first select:

```
select distinct 'A' as col_0_0_ 
from widget_a widget0_
where widget0_.creation_timestamp>?
```

Is there an obvious reason why JPA would disregard everything after the first select statement?  If it makes any difference, I am using Hibernate 4.1.9 as the JPA implementation, with a MySQL database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JPQL](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_2/jpa/jpql.html) has no such concept as UNION. So consequently any "query" that has it is not JPQL and so ought to be rejected as invalid JPQL (which [DataNucleus JPA](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_2) certainly would do)

Comment: Interesting.  I figured Hibernate would have complained at me.  If JPQL doesn't handle unions, are there alternatives that might serve a similar purpose?

Comment: are "WidgetA" and "WidgetB" in the same inheritance tree? If so then do a JPQL of the common superclass, and you may get a UNION SQL statement issued. Otherwise just issue two JPQL queries and merge the results in your code

Comment: Thanks for setting me straight on unions in queries and for the suggestions.  I have other questions now but they are a little off topic for this question.  I figured it was better to post them separately.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15080555/jpql-equivalent-of-sql-query-using-unions-and-selecting-constants

Comment: EclipseLink supports UNION in JPQL, http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/j_union.htm#union