# Questions about query several tables through JPA

Tags: sql, database, spring, jakarta-ee, jpa

Recently, I need to use JPA in my project.
However, I encountered some difficulties. JPA seemes to be harder than I thought.
So, I post my problem here, hoping that, some guys may help me.

There are two tables operation and analysis, the sql is like the following:

```
select op_id from operation where flag = 1 
union
select an_id from analysis where on_type = "processed";
```

`op_id` and `an_id` are two column names actually means the same.

Can anyone help me writing a JPA version of this?
I'm very grateful of that.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

JPQL does not support unions.

You have four options:

1. You can create a View in your DB that would do the unioning, then map to that view
2. Write a native SQL that does the union (since you only need the ID, this is a valid option)
3. If the IDs are distinct, you can run two queries, and concatenate the result list (if not distinct, you could use `Set`s to filter duplications)
4. If you are using the latest (at least >=2.4) EclipseLink as a JPA provider, you can use [UNION](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/JPQL#UNION)

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15062501/jpa-only-executes-first-select-statement-in-union) here.

Comment: Also if using EclipseLink, UNION is supported (>=2.4)