# Need help converting Neo4j Cypher request to JPQL

Tags: jpa, neo4j, cypher, jpql

I have that Neo4j Cypher request that I need to convert to JPQL:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:worksForOrganisation]->
    (:Organisation)-[*0..2]->(:Organisation)
    -[:possessesResource|:accessesResource|:supportsResource]->(:Software)
    <-[:categoryContains]-(c:ResourceCategory)
WHERE id(p)=({personId})
RETURN c
```

This request starts from a unique `Person` with identifier `personId`.

We know that this person works for one (in rare cases, many) `Organisation`s.

We know that each organisation can possess, access or support a resource of type `Software`.

We want to return the `ResourceCategories` that "contain" the `Software`s that the person can use, given the fact that there may be associations between different organisations, that grant him/her the right to use a software from another Organisation.

The difficulties to convert it to JPQL come from :

1. (:Organisation)-[*0..2]->(:Organisation)
2. (:Organisation)-[:possessesResource|:accessesResource|:supportsResource]->(:Software)

**Point 1** : the `(:Organisation)-[*0..2]->(:Organisation)` means an optional relationship between at most three "Organisation" nodes. The idea is that,  having found a "Organisation" node, we are also interested by all paths starting from at most two other "Organisations" that are associated with the organisation the person is working for.

**Point 2** : `(:Organisation)-[:possessesResource|:accessesResource|:supportsResource]->(:Software)` means that, having found a "Organisation", it can be related to a "Software" with three kinds of relationships (or even by many relationships of the various kinds).

**My idea so far** (really incomplete, I know) :

```
@Query("SELECT rc FROM Person p, Organisation o1, Organisation o2, Organisation o3, Software s, ResourceCategory rc " +
        "WHERE p.id = :personId " +
        "AND o1 MEMBER OF p.worksForOrganisations " +
        "AND s MEMBER OF rc.resources")
Set<ResourceCategoryEntity> getCategoriesForPerson(@Param("personId") Long personId);
```

**Questions** :

- how can I reproduce the [*0..2] optional relationships? Do I need a UNION between three requests, one with only Organisation o1, the second with Organisations o1 and o2, the last one with Organisations o1, o2 and o3?
- can the various kinds of relationships be converted to "AND ((s MEMBER OF o1.possessesResource) OR (s MEMBER OF o1.accessesResource) OR (s MEMBER OF o1.supportsResource r))"?

Thanks!

**UPDATE** : as [JPQL doesn't support UNION](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15062689/1528942), then how can I reproduce the "variable length join"?

Comment: you say you want to convert it to SQL, yet then go on about JPQL. Best decide which is your target

Comment: Ok I fixed my message, it's JPQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After **a lot** of work, we believe we found a corresponding JPQL request.

In case someone wonders how to mimic the difficult part of the Cypher request, which is the path of variable length `(Organisation)-[*0..2]->(Organisation)`, I believe we cannot do it in JPQL at all, and we had to treat all possible instances of the super class "Organisation", which are "Community", "Institution", "TeachingDepartment" and "AdministrativeDepartment".

```
SELECT DISTINCT (rc) FROM ResourceCategory rc JOIN rc.resources d
WHERE d.id IN ( SELECT e.id FROM Documentation e, Organisation o, Person u
                WHERE u.id = :personId
                  AND o MEMBER OF u.worksForOrganisations
                  AND (   o = e.organisationPossessingResource
                       OR o = e.organisationSupportingResource
                       OR o MEMBER of e.organisationsHavingAccessToResource
                      )
              )
   OR d.id IN ( SELECT d.id FROM Documentation d, Organisation o
                WHERE TYPE(o) IN (Institution)
                  AND (   o = d.organisationPossessingResource
                       OR o = d.organisationSupportingResource
                       OR o MEMBER of d.organisationsHavingAccessToResource
                      )
                  AND o.id IN (
                     SELECT i.id FROM Institution i, AdministrativeDepartment ad, Person u
                     WHERE u.id = :personId
                       AND ad MEMBER OF u.worksForOrganisations
                       AND ad MEMBER OF i.administrativeDepartments
                     )
               )
   OR d.id IN ( SELECT d.id FROM Documentation d, Organisation o
                WHERE TYPE(o) IN (Institution)
                  AND (   o = d.organisationPossessingResource
                       OR o = d.organisationSupportingResource
                       OR o MEMBER of d.organisationsHavingAccessToResource
                      )
                  AND o.id IN (
                     SELECT i.id FROM Institution i, TeachingDepartment td, Person u
                     WHERE u.id = :personId
                       AND td MEMBER OF u.worksForOrganisations
                       AND td MEMBER OF i.teachingDepartments
                     )
              )
   OR d.id IN ( SELECT d.id FROM Documentation d, Organisation o
                WHERE TYPE(o) IN (Community)
                  AND (   o = d.organisationPossessingResource
                       OR o = d.organisationSupportingResource
                       OR o MEMBER of d.organisationsHavingAccessToResource
                      )
                  AND o.id IN (
                     SELECT c.id FROM Community c, Institution i, AdministrativeDepartment ad, Person u
                     WHERE u.id = :personId
                       AND ad MEMBER OF u.worksForOrganisations 
                       AND ad MEMBER OF i.administrativeDepartments
                       AND c MEMBER OF i.communities
                     )
              )
   OR d.id IN ( SELECT d.id FROM Documentation d, Organisation o
                WHERE TYPE(o) IN (Community)
                  AND (   o = d.organisationPossessingResource 
                       OR o = d.organisationSupportingResource 
                       OR o MEMBER of d.organisationsHavingAccessToResource
                      )
                  AND o.id IN (
                     SELECT c.id FROM Community c, Institution i, TeachingDepartment td, Person u
                     WHERE u.id = :personId
                       AND td MEMBER OF u.worksForOrganisations
                       AND td MEMBER OF i.teachingDepartments
                       AND c MEMBER OF i.communities
                  )
              )
   OR d.id IN ( SELECT d.id FROM Documentation d, Organisation o
                WHERE TYPE(o) IN (Community)
                  AND (   o = d.organisationPossessingResource
                       OR o = d.organisationSupportingResource
                       OR o MEMBER of d.organisationsHavingAccessToResource
                      )
                 AND o.id IN (
                     SELECT c.id FROM Community c, Institution i, Person u 
                     WHERE u.id = :personId 
                       AND i MEMBER OF u.worksForOrganisations 
                       AND i MEMBER OF c.institutions
                     )
              )
```

**Foot-note** : this demonstrates that Cypher absolutely rock, being so much simpler than the equivalent JPQL. Hopefully it will become a standard, so the reason why I had to switch to a relational database will one day disappear.